# htaccess issue on codeigniter setup on ubuntu

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu

```
    My website open properly when I type `www.abc.com` on browser but when I type `abc.com` it opens page of subdomain which I have hosted which is `admin.abc.com`.

    But the url still says `abc.com`

    Here is my .htaccess code:

    <!-- language: lang-bash -->

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache and have configured virtual hosts for both domains.
    Any guidance will be highly appreciated.
```

Here is my conf file for abc.com which is uploaded on the server for both domain and sub-domain.

```
    <!-- language: lang-bash -->
    # domain: abc.com
    # public: /var/www/abc.com/public_html/

    <VirtualHost *:443>
      SSLEngine On
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/c8d39f3574580de6.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/abc.key
      SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

      <Directory /var/www>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
      </Directory>

      # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
      ServerAdmin admin@abc.com
      ServerName  abc.com
      ServerAlias abc.com

      # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
      DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
      DocumentRoot /var/www/abc.com/public_html
      # Log file locations
      LogLevel warn
      ErrorLog  /var/www/abc.com/log/error.log
      CustomLog /var/www/abc.com/log/access.log Combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

Here is my conf file for admin.abc.com

```
<!-- language: lang-bash -->

# domain: admin.abc.com
# public: /var/www/admin.abc.com/public_html/

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin admin@abc.com
  ServerName  admin.abc.com
  ServerAlias admin.abc.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/admin.abc.com/public_html
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/admin.abc.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/admin.abc.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

do let us know if above conf files where helpful to determine the issue, Looking forward to your response.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your Virtual Host configuration correctly configured?

I would recommend you using a configuration file instead of .htaccess if you are able to.

*(under: **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled** or **sites-available**, if it has not been activated yet)*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        # With this configuration when you try to reach both www.abc.com
        # and abc.com it directs you to the same place.
        # If you got a subdomain, you should create a separate .conf file
        # with the correct configurations as well.

        ServerAdmin admins@email.com
        ServerName www.abc.com
        ServerAlias abc.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/websites/folder

        # Some more comments...

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # More comments... 
</VirtualHost>
```

After editing this, do not forget to restart the Apache server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i already have two conf files for both abc.com and admin.abc.com
and both of them are pointing to their respective root directory. Not sure why its happening, being struggling on it for couple of days now.

Comment: Could you post those two .config files somewhere I could have a look at it? And why are you using the .htaccess if you have a .config file?

Comment: i have added the files above, can you pls check. I am using htaaccess coz to redirect all http to https

Comment: On the first .config file, try setting the ServerName to www.abc.com

Comment: i tried that its not working..!!!
also some desktops it redirects to www but on some it does not. what could be the issue?